# Android studio autocomplete order

Tags: android, android-studio, intellisense

There is something that bothers me a lot on Android Studio. Basically, the keyword like **void** no longer take priority in auto complete. I have therefore to type the whole word. I have no idea why the studio thinks it shouldn't take priority, but look in at this screenshot. [image]

I barely use that function. but for some reason, AS puts it at the top, therefore I often press enter, and type the wrong function instead of just completing with void. This happens to many other popular keywords, instead of the keyword taking priority, and random function comes at top.

is there a way to force AS to respect popular keywords priority? I really really use "void" a lot, and this is driving me crazy!

EDIT: Now i realize it's trying to add some setters. But I am not interested in those. I'd rather get my "void" autocomplete back when i type v-o